# VARCHAR NULL storage

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, null

I read somewhere online and in a Microsoft Press book there is a field declaration attribute that can be used to indicate NULL VARCHAR values should not consume space at the leaf-level instead of consuming a few characters per leaf.

Could someone help me identify where that attribute is?

I cant remember what the Attribute keyword is but I remember seeing it because of the value of saving the empty 2 bytes and make it a 0 byte storage for no data.

Comment: Pretty sure you are asking about SPARSE columns. Do you have further questions about them, or did you just need to be reminded what they're called?

Comment: I knew it was new to 2008(r2) but couldnt remember the keyword for the new attribute for varchar data  type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are talking about [SPARSE columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx).